# Need help using TAIL and SED to find a string pattern and use part of that string pattern as a variable

Tags: variables, sed, minecraft, tail

What I need is to monitor the last line of a file (more specificly the `latest.log` file for a Minecraft server) and test to see if it contains any predetermined strings.

Example:

I want to see when a specific player says a certain string. When the player says the specific string the last line of the `latest.log` will look like this:

```
[12:34:56] [Server thread/INFO]: <minecraft_player> string_i_need
```

When `minecraft_player` says `string_i_need` I need it to trigger other things but I think I know how to do that I just need to know how to isolate the key elements as variables.

What I want to isolate as variables:

```
$TIME = [12:34:56]
$NAME = minecraft_player
$STRING = string_i_need
```

I also need to make sure I don't detect a "false positive" if a malicious player were to say `[12:34:56] [Server thread/INFO]: <minecraft_player> string_i_need` causeing the last line of the latest.log file to look like:

```
[12:34:56] [Server thread/INFO]: <malicios_player> [12:34:56] [Server thread/INFO]: <minecraft_player> string_i_need
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tail piped to sed piped to grep to capture the time.

```
tail -n 1 log.log | sed -n "/^\[..:..:..\] \[Server thread\/INFO\]: \<minecraft_player\> string_i_need$/p" | grep -o "\[..:..:..\]"
```

`tail -n 1 log.log` will return the last line of a file called log.log
`| sed -n` will match the line if minecraft_player said string_i_need (false positives are declined) and then `grep -o` will print the time.